# python failing __eq__ test

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm new to python and I'm learning to use `pytest`. I have a class defined as:

```
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, *rows):
        row_length = len(rows[0])
        for row in rows:
            # TODO skip first
            if len(row) != row_length:
                raise SystemError("Rows does not have equal length")

        self._rows = [*rows]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(self, other.__class__) and \
               all([x == y for x, y in zip_longest(self._rows, other._rows)])

    # other methods omitted for simplicity...
```

and I wrote a test for `__eq__(self, other)` like this:

```
def test_eq():
    m1 = Matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
    m2 = Matrix([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
    m3 = Matrix([1,2,3],[5,4,6])
    assert m1 == m2
    assert m2 == m1
    assert m2 != m3
```

Which should pass because `m1` and `m2` has the same rows, and `m3` has a difference in second row. However when I run this test I have the output:

```
    def test_eq():
        m1 = Matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
        m2 = Matrix([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
        m3 = Matrix([1,2,3],[5,4,6])
>       assert m1 == m2
E       assert <exercises.matrix.Matrix object at 0x10ccd67d0> == <exercises.matrix.Matrix object at 0x10ccd6810>
```

What am I missing here? I'm using Python 3.7.4 and pytest version 5.1.2. Thanks in advance for your comments/answers

---

**NOTE:** I changed the implementation based on ggorlen answer, but I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: The bug is in your `.row` method, which you don't show us.

Comment: I think this is not the case, that method is tested and working properly, but maybe I'm passing wrong parameters. Will check. Thanks

Comment: Did you inadvertently omit the `row()` method? Please show a [mcve] if that method exists.

Comment: @ggorlen I added some details to the class. Please check the edit. Thanks for your time

Comment: Looks like the same problem--no method named `_rows()` exists. Either use the private data class `_rows[]` with brackets or call the function `.row()` with parenthesis. See my answer. There's still a logic problem: if the `other` matrix has more rows than `self`, you can get false positives because the loop never considers the extra rows.

Comment: @ggorlen I assume you commented before my last edition. Please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines in your comparison should be something like:

```
for i, i_row in enumerate(self._rows):
    if i_row != other._rows[i]:
        return False
```

But this still won't return the correct result if `other` has more rows than `self`, so:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(self, other.__class__) and \
           len(other._rows) == len(self._rows) and \
           all([x == y for x, y in zip(self._rows, other._rows)])
```

The property is called `_rows`, and we need to use `[]` to index into a list, not parentheses.

A potentially faster version that can bail early on failed comparisons is:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(self, other.__class__) and \
      len(other._rows) == len(self._rows):
        for i, row in enumerate(self._rows):
            if row != other._rows[i]:
                return False

        return True

    return False
```

---

In your test, you might have a typo:

```
m1 = Matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) # <-- this matrix has an extra `[]` wrapper
m2 = Matrix([1,2,3],[4,5,6])   # <-- but this one just uses flat lists
```

so these matrices will not be equal.

---

Minor suggestions:

- Raise a `ValueError` or `ArgumentError` instead of a `SystemError` on bad parameters.
- Consider using [Numpy.matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) instead of rolling your own matrix.

Comment: I will try your solution. About Numpy.matrix, the fact is that this is an exercise, I'm supposed to use only standard library functions. Thanks for your time

Comment: I changed `__eq__` as you suggested but I'm having the same issue. Check the edition

Comment: Did you fix the typo `m1 = Matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` (extra `[]`s)?

Comment: I believed that's a valid syntax for a list of list, but seems not. Thank you very much, it's working now and your solution is cleaner and elegant than mine

Comment: Sure, but there's no way m1 will equal m2 then. You're comparing a 1x1 matrix (that happens to contain as its one element a nested list) to a 2x3 matrix. The syntax is valid, but it represents something different than you think (print the contents in the initializer to see what they really are). No problem!

Comment: Yup, I realized that and fixed the comment

Comment: BTW what is the difference of using `zip()` with an extra comparison vs `zip_longest()`?

Comment: The `zip_longest` approach is less efficient, because if the lists aren't equal, it checks everything until it hits a `None == some_row_list`. So if we just check the lengths up front, we can return immediately if the lengths are different and can use regular `zip` because we're guaranteed that we have the same number of rows. It's still not the most efficient solution because there's no early break if two lists fail the comparison (use a regular loop instead of a list comprehension/`any`), but it should be correct.